# FTP site isolation between different users on different sub folders?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7, ftp

I have a simple FTP site, let say on C:\FTP. Now I need to give permmission to UserA on C:\FTP\UserA and give perm mission to UserB on C:\FTP\UserB. I need to make sure that these access are isolated. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I need the user isolation in IIS 7,

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-user-isolation-in-iis-7